# I cannot reuse the function from my library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `ClassLibrary` library and have the function

```
public string AddEmp (string query)
```

On `WebService1.asmx` I have declared

```
using ClassLibrary;
```

but I can't reuse the `AddEmp` function. How do i fix it?

Sorry for my weak English skill

AddEmp:
[image]

AddNewData:
[image]

Comment: please consider adding a sample of your code.

Comment: Please show code as text instead of images. If you have an error message from Visual Studio paste that as well. Code is not a picture, it's words, so please treat it as such. Then people can copy/paste it to write answers and make demos, it's searchable for other users and usually much more readable too. There are tools in the editor you can use to format the code. Please bear this in mind for the future, it will make people much happier about your question. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway the problem is that you didn't create an instance of your class. Please try to learn the basics of object-oriented programming, as this is a fairly basic error. You have to call the method from an instance of the class it belongs to. The `using` statement just makes a namespace available, it doesn't actually create any objects, and it doesn't make the functions in the classes of that namespace magically part of your current class - it can't, that might create conflicts. `Class1 cls = new Class1();
cls.AddEmp(data);` should fix your issue. But please take a tutorial!

Comment: P.S. ASMX is old obsolete technology. If you're only just learning ASP.NET and C# now, you would be better to learn something more up to date such as Web API for implementing this kind of functionality. Maybe it would even be wise to start with .NET Core rather than "traditional" .NET Framework - .NET Core is very likely to be the primary platform in the future.